# How do I connect NuxtJS login auth to my backend with axios?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, nuxt.js

I currently have a frontend auth app somewhat made with NuxtJS, where it will take in username/password fields and then use `this.$auth.login` to login.

I'm confused, though, on how to pass this info to the backend so it can verify that the username/password combination is correct. Currently my code will direct to the next page no matter what I put in the fields (makes sense since I haven't configured anything yet). I understand I need to use Axios POST requests somehow and I made an attempt at that but I don't really know what to do next. I don't know how to grab the token that contains my user data and push it to my backend (adonisJS) so I can check it against the database.

My `login.vue` component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-form @submit.prevent="loginUser">
      <div>
        <v-label>Username</v-label>
        <v-text-field color='red' v-model="login.username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <v-label>Password</v-label>
        <v-text-field color='red' v-model="login.password" /> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <v-btn type="submit" color='purple'>Submit</v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loginUser() {        
    const response = await this.$axios.post("/auth/users", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        }).then(
        await this.$auth.login({
            data: {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }
        }).then(() => {
            this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        ).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

My `nuxt.js.config` (relevant parts)

```js
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: false, // <--- Default "user"
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      }
    } 
  },

   router: {
     middleware: ['auth']
   },
```

Can anyone help me out with what I need to do with axios? (I checked my storage to see if there was a token there and it just says "false".) Thank you!

Comment: Try `$auth.setUser` after `$auth.login`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use axios post, this is how you should log in

```js
methods: {
  async loginUser() {        
    try {
      //this will attempt to log in, and if successful it'll go to the home page unless you change the default redirects
      const fields = {email: this.email, password: this.password};
      await this.$auth.loginWith("local", { data: fields });
      console.log("login successful");
    } catch (errors) {
      //an error occurred, could be wrong password or any other type of error
      console.error(errors);
    }
  }
}
```

> local is the strategy name and means that it's your own auth server, if you were using google for example you'd put google there, check out [loginwith](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/#loginwithstrategyname-args) and [local](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local)

the auth library already knows that your login url is `/auth/login` since you stated that in the nuxt config.

if you want to control where it goes after the login, look into the `redirect` options in the `nuxt.config` [from the docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options#redirect) and specifically in this case `home`.

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    home: '/'
  }
}
```